# GMSPlacesClient cancel request

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

In one of my apps users have an ability to search for a location by its name. I am using Google Maps APIs to display autocompleted suggestions with the help of `GMSPlacesClient`.

Code below illustrates how I do this:

```
func performSearch() {
        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter.City
        placesClient?.autocompleteQuery(searchBar.text!, bounds: nil, filter: filter, callback: { (results, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            // update results
        })
    }
```

This code works very well. However, I noticed one scenario in which it sort of fails. One example is if I search for "Chicago". If I type "Ch" very fast sometimes the results are returned for "Ch" correctly, but sometimes I obtain the results for "C". The problem arises because these are asynchronous requests and I am performing the search each time user types something. So, even though the request for "C" was initiated before "Ch" it can return last.

I therefore need to cancel all previous initiated requests before I start a new one. However, I couldn't find a way of doing this. Does anyone know how to achieve it?

## Update

I have tried to use a workaround:

```
    let string = myResults[0].attributedFullText
    string.enumerateAttribute(kGMSAutocompleteMatchAttribute, inRange: NSMakeRange(0, string.length), options: .Reverse) { (value, range, stop) -> Void in
        if value != nil {
            let t = NSString(string: string.string)
            let str = t.substringWithRange(range)
            //now compare with original search string
        }
    }
```

This fixes the issue with Chicago (and other similar cases). However, such approach will disable autocomplete suggestions when user makes a typo because the matched string and original search string are always different in this case.

So, the question still remains open. An ideal approach would be to cancel all previously initiated requests. If Google also stored the initial search string an approach similar to that presented above could work, but it looks like the original search string is not returned after request...

It seems like the only option is to not use the SDK but to use Alamofire to send requests. Those requests can then be easily cancelled. However, I am not sure how good this is...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I cancel an ongoing request in \[GMSPlacesClient autocompleteQuery\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692599/how-can-i-cancel-an-ongoing-request-in-gmsplacesclient-autocompletequery)

Comment: @spiv are you really suggesting that a question asked on Nov 10 is a duplicate of question asked on Nov 13? :)

Comment: Heh.  Clearly yours was first, but by chance the Nov 13 one got an answer first :)