# How can I cancel an ongoing request in [GMSPlacesClient autocompleteQuery]?

Tags: ios8, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I would like to add autocomplete feature to my app.
My idea is to use autocompleteQuery:bounds:filter:callback from GMSPlacesClient class.
While user is typing, I would like to call that method, but I guess if I send several requests, I could receive responses out of order. For that reason I would like to cancel the current one, but I don't see a way.
Maybe it is implemented internally, I don't know.
Any help or suggestion? Thanks a lot.

I realised responses could come out of order. I created a small sample with a textfield and one table.
I sent a request every time user taps a letter and the results say that there is no automatic request cancelation or order.

```
2015-11-13 15:16:14.668 TestGooglePlaces[5233:60b] u
2015-11-13 15:16:15.550 TestGooglePlaces[5233:60b] ut
2015-11-13 15:16:15.700 TestGooglePlaces[5233:60b] uto
2015-11-13 15:16:15.967 TestGooglePlaces[5233:60b] utop
2015-11-13 15:16:16.552 TestGooglePlaces[5233:60b] utopi
2015-11-13 15:16:23.035 TestGooglePlaces[5233:60b] Results for u
2015-11-13 15:16:23.079 TestGooglePlaces[5233:60b] Results for utop
2015-11-13 15:16:23.087 TestGooglePlaces[5233:60b] Results for utopi
2015-11-13 15:16:23.093 TestGooglePlaces[5233:60b] Results for ut
2015-11-13 15:16:23.155 TestGooglePlaces[5233:60b] Results for uto
```

How can I fix that problem? The only idea I have is to use the REST web service and cancel the ongoing requests manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We on the Places API for iOS team are aware of this problem and are working on it. In the next release of the SDK we'll have a class which takes care of managing these requests and returning them in the correct order.

In the meantime, you can manage these requests by keeping track of the order that the requests came in and ignoring responses if they're too old:

```
@implementation YourClass {
  NSUInteger _sequenceNumber;
  __block NSUInteger _mostRecentResponseNumber;
}

- (void)autocompleteQuery:(NSString *)query {
  NSUInteger thisSequenceNumber = ++_sequenceNumber;
  [_placesClient autocompleteQuery:query
                            bounds:nil
                            filter:nil
                          callback:^(NSArray * _Nullable results, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                            if (thisSequenceNumber <= _mostRecentResponseNumber) {
                              return;
                            }
                            _mostRecentResponseNumber = thisSequenceNumber;
                            // process results here
                      }];
}
```

Not the nicest, but it should work until we release a better way of doing this :)

Comment: Actually that was my first idea but I implemented a NSOperation/NSOperationQueue and only returned the result when the operation was not cancelled. Of course I call cancelAllOperations before sending a new request/operation. I guess yours is easier and shorter.
BTW, there is a memory problem with GMSAutocompleteMatchFragment in the bold text code (it grows until the infinite and beyond) and in one sample code in the website you forgot calling super viewDidLoad. Thanks a lot for reply.

Comment: Glad you've found a solution! The memory problem sounds like something we should fix. Could you report it on the issue tracker(https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list)? This will help us with diagnosis and prioritization.

Comment: Just following up on this: we've just released a new version of the SDK with the GMSAutocompleteFetcher class, which will take care of this for you.

See the docs at https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_fetcher

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will check that.